# Не записываются данные в базу

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite3

Код составлен по всем требованиям, но не записывает информацию в `somedatabase.db`:

```
import sqlite3


def insert_data(values):
    cursor = sqlite3.connect("somedatabase.db").cursor()
    sql = "Insert into Product(Name,Price) values (?,?)"
    cursor.execute(sql, values)
    sqlite3.connect("somedatabase.db").commit()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    product = ("Espresso", 1.5)
    insert_data(product)
```

Вопрос банальный: "что делать"?

Comment: Не connect'иться к одной и той же базе два раза, connect должен быть ровно один

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте так:

```
import sqlite3

def insert_data(values):
    conn = sqlite3.connect("somedatabase.db")
    sql = "Insert into Product(Name,Price) values (?,?)"
    conn.execute(sql,values)
    conn.commit()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    product = ("Espresso",1.5)
    insert_data(product)
```

---

Думаю, проблема была в двух сессиях: в первой вы добавили данные, во второй вы их записали в базу. Но, добавленные данные были в первой сессии, а не во второй, поэтому `commit()` не работает